# Dini's theorem and monotonicity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is Dini's theorem can be applied for a function series such that for every $x$ there's an $N_x$ where for every $n>N_x:$ $f_n(x) \ge f_{n+1}(x)$; Meaning, the monotonicity start **somewhere** in the series, for every $x$.

Comment: No, it can't. Consider $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}\quad nx &, 0 \leqslant x \leqslant \frac{1}{n} \\ 2 - nx &, \frac{1}{n} < x \leqslant \frac{2}{x} \\ \qquad 0 &, x \geqslant \frac{2}{n}\end{cases}$$ on $[0,1]$. The convergence is not uniform, but eventually monotonic at all points.

Answer (score 6):

It is not sufficient to conclude uniform convergence if the sequence only becomes eventually monotonic at each point. That does not prevent a sliding hump like we have with the functions

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} \quad nx &, 0 \leqslant x \leqslant \frac{1}{n} \\ 2 - nx &, \frac{1}{n} < x \leqslant \frac{2}{n} \\ \quad 0 &, \frac{2}{n} < x \end{cases}$$

on $[0,1]$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$. We have $f_n(x) \to 0$ for all $x$, so the limit function is continuous, and $f_n(1/n) = 1$, so the convergence is not uniform. If we set $N_0 = 1$ and $N_x = \lceil 1/x\rceil$ for $x > 0$, then the sequence $\bigl(f_n(x)\bigr)_{n\geqslant N_x}$ is monotonic for all $x$, so the sequence satisfies the conditions.

Of course the convergence is uniform if we demand that there is an $N$ such that the sequence $\bigl(f_n\bigr)_{n \geqslant N}$ is monotonic, but we need a uniform index at which the sequence becomes monotonic, the index can't (arbitrarily) depend on the point.

Answer (score 1):

In the version of Dini's theorem that I had, it was already consider this case. I attach you the proof, with your case conisdered. I hope it's useful.

**Claim:**

Let $(E,d)$ be a compact metric space and $f_n:E \to\mathbb N$ a succession of continuous functions. Let $\{f_n\}_n$ converge pointwise to a continuous function $f$. And, for every $x\in E$ it should exist an $N_x \in \mathbb N$ such that for every $n>N_x$, $f_n(x) \geq f_{n+1}(x)$.

Then $\{f_n\}_n$ converge uniformly to $f$.

**Proof:**

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $x \in E$ be given.

- $\exists N_x$ such that $\forall n>N_x$
  $$f_{n+1}(x) \leq f_n(x) \Rightarrow f(x) \leq \cdots \leq f_{n+2}(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x) \leq f_n(x) \Rightarrow$$
  $$\Rightarrow f(x) -f_n(x) \leq 0 \Rightarrow f(x) -f_n(x) < \epsilon/3$$
- Because $f$ and $f_n$ are continuous, it exists and open neighbourhood $V(x)$ of $x$ such that if $y \in V(x)$ then 
  $$|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/3$$ and 
  $$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\epsilon/3$$

On the other hand:
$$ |f(y)-f_n(y)| = |f(y)-f(x)+f(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \leq  $$
$$|f(y)-f(x)| + |f(x)-f_n(x)| + |f_n(x)-f_n(y)| < \epsilon/3 + \epsilon/3 + \epsilon/3 = \epsilon$$

Because $\{V(x) : x \in E\}$ is an open cover of the compact $E$, then it exist a finite subcover $\{V(x_1),V(x_2), \cdots, V(x_p)\}$.

If we define $N:=max \{ N_{x_1},N_{x_2},\cdots,N_{x_p} \}$. Then, for each $x \in E$, $x$ will also belong to one $V(x_i)$ and then $\forall n \geq N$
$$|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon  (\forall x \in E)$$
Therefore $\{f_n\}_n$ converge uniformly to $f$.

Comment: That's incorrect, consider $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}\quad nx &, 0 \leqslant x \leqslant \frac{1}{n} \\ 2 - nx &, \frac{1}{n} < x \leqslant \frac{2}{x} \\ \qquad 0 &, x \geqslant \frac{2}{n}\end{cases}$$ on $[0,1]$. The convergence is not uniform, but eventually monotonic at all points.

Comment: But the limit of that function isn't continuous. The limit won't be defined on 0, and it should be because you need the metric space to be compact.

Comment: The pointwise limit is $0$, you can't get more continuous than constant.

Comment: The limit function is $f(x)=0$ on the interval $(0,C]$ but it isn't defined on the point $x=0$. It needs to be defined in a compact set.

Comment: We have $f_n(0) = 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Sorry, my last answers weren't really clear, but I keep believing that $f$ is not continuous on $0$. To be continuous shouldn't it be verifying 
$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = f(0)$?

$$f(0)=\lim_{n \to \infty}$ f_n(0) = \lim_{n \to \infty}$ 0 = 0$$.
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\lim_{n \to \infty} nx = 1$$

Comment: The limit function is $f\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R};\; x \mapsto 0$. That is continuous. For any fixed $x > 0$, we have $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n \geqslant 2/x$. And we have $f_n(0) = 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32375/discussion-between-tlarigram-and-daniel-fischer).